# Badges are not being updated, even though I have visited the site for more than 30 days

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days, electorate-badge

I have account on SO from last 5 months and my badges are not being updated, even though I have visited the site for more than 30 days.

**EDIT**:Screenshot included in response to your comments.

[image: for vote total number of vote cast]
[30 consecutive days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azCkW.png)

Comment: I suppose you're expecting to earn the [Enthusiast badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/71/enthusiast)? Do you meet all the requirements?

Comment: Did you visit on consecutive days?

Comment: You do realize that you only gain the badge for 30 days in a row and not just for 30 days with gaps between them

Comment: yes dear i no the requirement.

Comment: @Akki: Its better to post your screenshot of 30 days visit

Comment: thanks guys i got my Enthusiast badge but  Electorate is still not in its place.

Comment: Re your current edit: You only just "today" have reached the required voting totals. You need to wait for the proper update cycle. Give it a day; you'll have it. It's not instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the 24-hour periods which count as days here are based on either GMT or UTC. Also, just to make sure, you did see the badge specifies 30 *consecutive* days? So every day for 30 continuous days you visited the Stack Overflow site (and logged in)?

*EDIT:* As for the Electorate badge, please read the badge descriptions carefully.

> Voted on 600 **questions** and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

You've only voted on about 350 questions so far.

Comment: i included the screenshot.

Comment: It should award at the end of the 30th day I would say. Wait until tomorrow.

Comment: okay but for number of votes? it was 600 a day before yesterday.

Comment: Nope its not true.The 30th day visit must gain you the badge

Comment: thanks guys i got my Enthusiast badge but  Electorate is still not in its place.

Answer (score 12):

This particular badge usually takes up to 3 hours past midnight UTC to actually be awarded.

Have patience, young <s>grasshopper</s> unicorn.

For example:
Here on Meta, my Enthusiast badge was awarded at `01:15:25Z`.
Over on Gaming.SE, my Enthusiast Badge was awarded at `02:52:29Z`.

Comment: Exactly - this badge has a 10% chance to run each grant cycle, so it's unlikely it'll be awarded right at UTC midnight.

Comment: @Akki: You need to have voted on 600 questions for Electorate. You've voted on 349...

Comment: @Akki: No, 600 questions, and 25% or more of your **total** votes are *on* questions.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, just be patient with Enthusiast.  I had the same issue, and eventually it was awarded.

Electorate can be a hard one to understand.  Basically you qualify if you have voted on (at least) 600 questions and your total number of votes is 2400 or less.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a nightly process like a couple other badges. I would wait until tomorrow.