# I hit 50 days with 200+ rep two months ago; where's my ticket to the Epic club?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, daily-reputation-badges

My english.stackexchange.com/reputation page informs me that I have "earned at least 200 reputation on 51 days".  Yesterday I had a 200+ day, but the most recent day before that was Jan. 13, as evidenced by my [rep profile page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/daniel?tab=reputation).  Is the system really two months latent?  Or is it something weird with the recent rep revolution?

Comment: I count you got more than 200 points 48 days.

Comment: out of curiosity what does english.stackexchange.com/reputation read for the number of times you earned at least 200 reputation?

Comment: 51 times.  I'll edit my question to make it clear that that's what I was referring to.

Comment: @kiam: It's 51 times: I counted and made a list of dates.

Comment: The epic club is full, sorry. We are not currently accepting new admissions. You *can* bribe your way in however by sending a sizeable PayPal donation to `pekka@gmx.de`

Comment: Epic seems a bit non-deterministic; if the comment below about it having only a 10% chance of running ever award cycle, it may be a long time coming. I notice because mine on ELU is now 11.5 hours overdue. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yesterday would have been your 50th day, as on June 26th you have to subtract the 100 association bonus which does not count (according to the [big list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/141525)). I think you're just playing the waiting game for the badge process to run, unless I'm missing something.

It's most likely, although it doesn't usually take this long for it to run. Maybe you're just unlucky. I'd assume that this badge has the same [10% chance of running](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123729/badges-are-not-being-updated-even-though-i-have-visited-the-site-for-more-than/123737#comment330279_123737) that the Fanatic-class badges have.

Comment: I still don't have it at 18:26 UTC.  I'll let you know when I get it.

Comment: Got it @ 1:31:51 UTC the day after.

Answer (score 4):

The scheduled process that grants that badge has 1/10 chance to run every hour, so don't expect a deterministic schedule.

Comment: You flip a 10-sided die every hour, and run the process if it comes up a 1?  Or you just run that process once every 10 hours?

Comment: We use random, I guess to avoid synchronicity problems.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217385/why-nondeterministic-algorithm-is-used-to-schedule-badge-calculation. Probably, I should have asked it here in comments.