# Copy Editor badge is not included to my account even after I have edited 500 posts

Tags: discussion, edits, badges, edit-badges

I have a problem regarding the `Copy Editor` badge. I have edited more than 500 posts in total. Still, I cannot receive `Copy Editor` badge in my account. And also, Copy Editor badge track (progress bar) also disappears from next badge track window.

[image: Copy Editor Badge Problem]

[image: Next badge track window]

Comment: Just wait a bit, badges are awarded by scheduled events, so not instantaneously after you qualify for them. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217379/295232

Comment: I have seen the message as "Congratulation - You earned Copy Editor badge" - Click to Pick. That's why I scared.

Comment: I can imagine; you're not the first person to be confused by this. I've updated the FAQ and are now voting to close this question as a duplicate. (That doesn't mean it's a bad question, not at all.)