# Meta sites in "Your Communities" display different reputation

Tags: bug, status-deferred, reputation, per-site-meta, communities-list

While using the top bar to navigate across communities, I noticed that the reputation displayed on meta sites on that list does not match the one of their corresponding main sites:

[image]

I have noticed on past situations that reputation gained takes a bit to "update" on the display on Meta sites (that is, if you gain rep on SO, for example, it will take some time for you to see your updated rep on MSO).

However, I have never noticed this behavior here, on the Sites List of the top bar. Furthermore, the "delay" here seems to be more severe, as the "outdated" rep showed is of several days ago (for example, I turned 3k on SO almost exactly a week ago, but the rep shown on MSO is still <3k).

**Any idea what could be causing this behavior?**

---

*Update:* 2 months later this persists: my main site rep updates correctly but their corresponding meta rep remains the same as in the image above.

---

*Update:* As per Catija's [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation#comment1056825_317269) I removed the site (MSO) and put it back in, but it didn't update the rep.

However, after removing one site (TWP Meta), waiting at least a day, and then adding it back I see that although the reputations still don't match, the number displayed did changed a bit (previously 29,924 but now 33,112):

[image]

Comment: How did you even get those Meta sites in your community list?

Comment: have no idea :0) don't recall adding them manually

Comment: If it helps, today (18 days later), both my meta reps are still unchanged bot the main site reps has changed

Comment: @rene just a wild thought I had. I do recall adding Meta TWP on my sites displayed on the SE Android App... could that be related perhaps?

Comment: turns out I just managed to add them on the site. I must have overlooked that when I tried it earlier today.

Comment: @rene you can add any site by just clicking on the \[edit\] button.

Comment: Also worth noting, that it doesn't just shows this rep difference on the list. If you open up the actual site and check your profile it has that different amount.

Comment: One month after posting, the situation persists... any new lights on this one?

Comment: Same thing here. In fact, it looks like it [affects all Meta sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIpfV.png).

Comment: This seems never updated for me (Android and Android M)

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ I see that the problem persist still...

Comment: Not to sound like your friendly neighborhood IT person... "Have you tried turning it off and back on again?" - By which I mean, have you tried removing it and adding it again? If you do this, does it have your updated rep or does it still show the same amount? If it shows the updated amount, does it update (check in a few days)?

Comment: @Catija I just tried doing that. Removed MSO from the list, put it back in, and rep is still the same for now... Let's see if it changes eventually

Comment: OK. If that doesn't work, might try removing it, waiting a day and adding it. Mostly I'm curious what will happen. I'm not sure it will fix anything but it may be more interesting than just sitting on it. :P Thanks for reporting this... you're not the only one. Hopefully we can figure this out.

Comment: @Catija to run both tests in parallel I did that second option with TWP Meta, will put it back on tomorrow and see what happens that way. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: @Catija I just added it back and something interesting happened, will edit and add pics

Comment: Huh... that's interesting... if that's caching, that's like... a month of caching. :(

Comment: Indeed, I was on that rep about... say, a month ago?

Comment: Same bug here for 3+ months @Catija: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382603/bug-reputation-stack-overflow-meta-and-main-site-more-than-30-days-different

Comment: @rene The meta sites show up in the "Your Communities" list if you add them to the sidebar in the mobile app; at least that's how they showed up in the list for me. I'm having the same bug fwiw.

Comment: My mobile app sidebar shows the same (incorrect) meta reps as my "Your Communities" list. Not sure if that's a new bug; I assume it's related to this one.

Comment: Thanks for tipping me off to the fact that you can add metas to your community list. I'd never [tried to edit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8mGj.png) before!

Comment: We'll be adding this to be looked into as part of our bug duty rotation.

Answer (score 12):

It seems the global reputation recalculation following the [change in question upvote reputation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers) in November 2019 did temporarily reset the reputation of Meta sites to their correct values, at least for me.

[image]

(My Meta Stack Overflow reputation in that list used to be 16k and a bit.) This didn't happen for all users (see the comments below) and the following months it remained stuck at 17,604. However, today (May 16th, 2020) I looked again and behold:

[image]

For Stack Overflow, it's (temporarily?) back to normal; the +2 on the main account is very recent. For Puzzling, the difference is still enormous. A few days ago (between June 10th and June 13th) it seems to have synced again; it's now 18,641 (main) vs. 18,627 (meta). Yesterday or today (July 17th), it synced again; [both are now on 18,759](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYyyT.png). Perhaps the sync job is non-deterministic, [like the badge award job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125108/295232)?

I hope this information may help in fixing the bug. The API is affected by a similar bug: [/me/associated doesn't return meta sites anymore](https://stackapps.com/q/8666/34061).

Comment: For me it was not reset.

Comment: Not for me......

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what date  "today" refers to. In six months from now it won't be obvious, and "today" could refer to any time between Nov 17, 2019 and May 16, 2020 if a visitor doesn't look at the edit history.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes, that makes sense

Comment: 16 k and a bit, or 16 and a bit k?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Considering it's referring to previous values not shown, 16k and a bit is likely correct.

Answer (score 9):

## The situation May 12, 2020

[image]

The difference in reputation between the main site and meta is remarkable, on EL&U it says I have 79, 849 while on meta the score is 60,505, the resulting gap between the two sites is nearly 20,000 rep. I have no idea how long this "bug" has been present but I noticed it for the first time yesterday (May 12, 2020) and then tried searching for answers/solutions today. To state the obvious, it seems that the main site reflects the current score accurately while meta doesn't.

When I visit the different meta sites, the scores tally.

I haven't been particularly active on my accounts with the exclusion of Meta... but MSE doesn't have its own meta, which we would agree would be *very* confusing, hence the reputation score on the screenshot just says 19,253.

## May 16, 2020

The mismatch in reputation is also replicated on my mobile, so that's *weird*.

[image: mobile screenshot 16-5-2020]