# User has 1 reputation on Interpersonal.SE but 189 on Interpersonal.meta

Tags: bug, reputation, per-site-meta

I was looking at the list of new meta members for IPS.SE and I came across a user UID [#22035](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22035) looking at the profile you can see their reputation is exactly 189.

But, if we go their main profile [here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/22035) you can see something abnormal is going on, their reputation is 1 and the user has no activity.

<sub>This is different from [Meta sites in "Your Communities" display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation) – this is not about Your Communities at all, it's about another user.</sub>

Comment: Is it possible that they were suspended?

Comment: The user did have reputation from an answer that is now deleted, but that was back on Sep 29. I'm not sure why their meta profile wouldn't have updated. Entirely possible we just don't bother if the user isn't actively visiting meta anyways.

Comment: SO... caching? ;p

Comment: @Devealte: This is a different user, rep shown in profile. Nothing to do with the site switcher at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ok, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @forest Nope, the user isn't suspended. Suspensions include a notice at the top and don't allow the meta cache to be slow.

Comment: @animuson whatever job doing the main/meta rep synchronization is broken. Pretty sure Nick can fix, if someone will poke him hard enough with a sharp enough stick. :)

Comment: @gnat that question is about delays measured in minutes; this one's been five weeks.

Comment: @forest suspensions also show on both main and meta profiles.