# Reputation counters for SO and MSO not in sync?

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta

SO says: 89008

[image: so]

MSO says: 88948

[image: mso]

Shouldn't SO and MSO be fully in sync?

Comment: There's a delay of up to one hour.

Comment: It's updated hourly on per-sites Meta, less often on weekends and holidays (nah, kidding). Can't seem to find the dupe though...

Comment: OK, never noticed that before...

Comment: Found it now, after searching for "synchronized hourly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's synchronized once per hour; see the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow **(synchronized hourly)**, though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Note that there is currently a bug in the site switcher; that reputation is off by 6-8 weeks now. See [Meta sites in "Your Communities" display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation)