# Image descriptions are very rarely written in by users

Tags: discussion, images

I have noticed that although when inserting an image part of the code that SE Inserts when you upload it is text saying "Enter image description here" but people very rarely put  image descriptions and that is really annoying for blind people.

I think it may be because not everybody who asks on a SE Site is techy and only some people will even think of modifying that code.

I think you should make entering the image description a required thing so that people don't just overlook it.

It's just so annoying having to always post comments like "What does that image show?", "What would you describe that image as?", etc...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I sometimes put a description, so "nobody ever puts image description" is wrong. You can edit to make it correct by something like "Many times people don't put descriptions".

Comment: Also, forcing the user to enter a description will result in much more "enter a description here", which IMO is worse than a blank description, or even "gjsdsjt" etc. All in all, bad idea which will NOT help a bit.

Comment: Then we just need to publicize the fact that blind people are actually sometimes on SE

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332006/how-can-i-write-good-alt-text/332015#332015

Comment: I would support request to change the default text to something like "Please add a short description to help blind people use the site", yes. But not block the option to post without entering a description.

Comment: It's also annoying for people who cannot view the images due to Imgur being blocked.

Comment: I think the major problem is that in most cases, editors are trying to inline screenshots, we simply do not have the time to describe every screenshot an author might supply.  Hard enough to get authors to actually provide screenshots.  If authors had the ability to inline screenshots but be placed in a review queue that might help.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard such a message will be picked up by screen readers and is more hurtful for the people listening to it. I suggest banner.

Comment: If it’s any consolation, I often edit posts on Stack Overflow to add image descriptions.

Comment: If the image contains text, I’ll leave a comment linking to [Why are images of text, code, and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged)

Comment: You would be justified in down voting any post that's unclear without a description of the image.

Comment: After down voting the post what’s the best way to let the user know why  it was downvoted