# Is there a consolidated source of accessibility guidelines for users posting questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accessibility

While Stack Exchange itself tries to be as accessible as possible, I have been unsuccessful in finding anything to help users in their posting accessible questions/answers.

Is there a consolidated source, like the Markdown Help page, that helps the user in formatting their questions/answers for accessibility?

Some of the common issues I have seen are:

- Bold and italicized text
- Entire paragraphs in bold or italics
- Lack of alt text or hover tags for images
- Using "here" or "click here" before a URL
- Images of code or text

I have done some editing to questions/answers to make them more accessible but I have come across users that question why the edit was done or roll it back. An "Accessibility" page like the Markdown Help page would go a long way in helping users post and edit questions/answers.

Note: Users' indifference or not being made aware of why accessibility is important has existed for a while as shown in an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327965/13889028) to "Does Stack Overflow strive to meet accessibility standards?".

Comment: Not to forget about [images of code, and other text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: What kind of "*editing to questions/answers to make them more accessible*" are you talking about; can you give examples? Because this lack of guidelines also means a lack of consensus about what is accessible and what isn't, so rollbacks are to be expected :)

Comment: @Joachim I did give four bullet points of examples. Are you asking for more detailed examples? Also to clarify, I am not talking about the site structure itself; I am looking to guide user's posting questions/answers.

Comment: Yes, specific examples: "*bold and italicized text*" doesn't say anything about *how* it is (supposed to be) used. Which is what you seem to be looking for, right?

Comment: @Joachim There doesn't seem to be any one list of guidelines for **users** to follow or understand what accessibility is. The examples I gave are what I, in my knowledge of accessibility, have come across and have edited.

Comment: Re *"or roll it back"*: Formatting changes and alt text changes make the diff in the default view ("Inline") *look* ***much more extensive*** than they really are. You could be explicit about that in the edit summary as (presumably) very few users are aware of this. Or in other words, they may *think* you have *completely* changed the post when you haven't.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum what I have noticed is that rollbacks are done because the post was formatted using a table instead of a blockquote or their version of the formatting was "more visually appealing" instead of being functional/inclusive.

Comment: This got a relatively comprehensive answer today: [How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394687/how-do-i-write-an-accessible-stack-exchange-post)

Comment: @zcoop98 Thank you, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything like the Markdown Help page that helps the user in formatting their questions/answers?

Yes, other Meta questions, e.g. [How can I write good alt text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332006/178179)

---

Update (2023-11-15). Newly posted guide: [How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394687/178179)

Comment: The Markdown Help page is a consolidated source, while your example is a single solution to an individual issue. This wouldn't be helpful for new users to understand how/why accessibility is useful.

Comment: @agarza got it. Then the answer is no: nothing aside from some meta questions AFAIK.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes. It’s not my fault if the answer is no.

Comment: But then answering yes is wrong.

Comment: @tripleee “like the Markdown Help page” is vague.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt shouldn't the solution to that be fixing it, rather than creating a new solution?

Comment: @KevinB I was answering the question  "Are there accessibility guidelines for users posting questions/answers?"