# Reputation in chat is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-review, reputation, chat

Reputation in chat is incorrect.

Example: Jon Skeet

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation&page=1: 1168k
- https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=accounts: >1250k

Comment: Are there other profiles in a similar situation? I triggered a profile refresh for Jon and that re-synced the rep, but that doesn't necessarily mean we don't have a more persistent issue at play here.

Comment: @AdamLear no idea

Comment: Fair! I'll tag this with [status-review] then for us to take a closer look at later.

Comment: @AdamLear Here's [another example chat profile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/350567/). It says 20k but the user has 22k+, and the username is also out of date for longer than it should be.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Cool, thanks for the link.

Comment: Related?: [Meta sites in “Your Communities” display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Nope, not related; that has to do with per-site meta profiles, while this one is about chat profiles.

Comment: Then a suggested/interesting reading :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus I wouldn't say it's relevant to this question. Chat profiles are normally synced every hour, and for most users, it works, but this post is reporting that it's not working for *some specific* users.

Comment: Another case https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/22295/slaks