# Change/edit my user icon link location?

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, network-profile

Can I alter which page I am sent when I click my user button (the customizable icon for me in the upper right of most Stack Exchange pages)?  The page I use the most is the 'network' page that shows ***all*** of my Stack Exchange communities, which requires searching for three different links from the page it sends me to currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative, since the profile button isn't customizable, you *can* customize which communities appear in the right-most menu icon's drop-down menu:

[image]

Clicking "edit" allows you to add, remove, and customize the order of the list with any site in the network, including Meta ones. Adding your desired communities here might make them even easier to access than going to the [network accounts page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts).

This menu doesn't also show badge, question, or answer counts like the network accounts page, but it does show your reputation for each site in the list (note that the meta reputation count is [a little strange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation)).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. In terms of users, you have to think of Stack Exchange primarily as 178 separate sites, and how you appear on them, or what you can do on them largely depends on your contributions *on that site only*.

As an alternative, you can add https://stackexchange.com/users/current (a direct link to your network profile) to your browser bookmarks, but that's about it.

Comment: Should probably append `?tab=accounts`, which I think is the page the OP is referring to.

Comment: @41686d6564 could be, yes. Let's see what they respond ...