# Are users dropped in Lifeboats without Lifejackets?

Tags: support, badges, lifejacket-lifeboat-badges

IPS Meta just got a round of Lifeboat badges awarded, [5 posts have earned someone a Lifeboat](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/110/lifeboat).

But not a single user has yet earned the [Lifejacket badge](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/109/lifejacket), even though the criteria for getting that one seem lower than for getting the Lifeboat.

Usually, with badges that come in silver and gold, you get both for the same post, or progress for the silver badge also counts towards the gold badge (think Good/Great Answer or Epic/Legendary badges).

Is this the same for Lifejacket and Lifeboat, and is there just a little hiccup now because they're awarded for old posts? Or is there something in the criteria that makes it impossible to get both a Lifejacket and Lifeboat badge for the same post?

Comment: this happened to me on SO, but then a bit later the jacket was awarded. It'll probably just take some time.

Comment: It's been over half an hour now... How long did it take for you?

Comment: approximately 1 hour and 5 minutes. https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b?tab=badges&sort=recent

Comment: That's too long. People might topple overboard and drown! :P I guess we'll see ;)

Comment: Quick, add the lifejackets-lifeboat tags before someone else does! :P

Comment: Too late! I knew it.

Comment: I'm still in the water, no jacket, no boat, no life ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA [You're too slow!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWDqswWm3Xg)

Comment: @rene I'll throw you a lifebelt.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog [So are you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329696/are-users-dropped-in-lifeboats-without-lifejackets?noredirect=1#comment1075552_329696), this whole comment thread is turning out to be one big shipwreck!

Comment: Looks like the life jacket badges just got awarded on IPS meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they're not. [This user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22973/glenschler) earned the only [Lifeboat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/259/lifeboat) on Ask Different for [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179785/121968), but also earned [Lifejacket](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/258/lifejacket?userid=22973) for it.

It's very likely that the script for Lifejackets hasn't run on IPS meta yet, and even if it ran, it's [non-deterministic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125108/295232) so please wait at least 24 hours for assuming any [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s in the implementation.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to have something to do not with the badge criteria, but with the badge scripts. The Lifeboat criteria are entirely a superset of the Lifejacket criteria - any answer that qualifies for the former, qualifies for the latter by definition. It seems like the scripts that are retroactively awarding the badge are not running at the same time.

For example, [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305749/why-do-users-often-ask-blatantly-off-topic-questions-here-on-meta/305752#305752) earned the Lifejacket badge around 80 minutes before it earned the Lifeboat badge - the reverse order as your case, but still, it confirms that answers eligible for Lifeboat are indeed also eligible for Lifejacket when it comes to retroactive awarding.